# R: Script plots open up in new window

Tags: r

Instead of being charged in the plot pane, plots now open in a new window[image: r plot in a different window than the console]
this does not happen with Rmd files
[image: rmd file chqrged plot in the same window as the r code]
How can i set the plots to open in the plot pane next to the code instead of a new tab?

general options are like this [image: general options]

I've tried this

> options(device = "RStudioGD")
> plot(DNase$conc, DNase$density)
> Error in .Call("rs_createGD") :
> C symbol name "rs_createGD" not in load table
> getOption("device")
> [1] "RStudioGD"
> dev.off()
> Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)

Comment: `dev.off()` should help

Comment: If you go to Tools < Global Options < Pane Layout . Is Plots checked in one of the four panes (probably bottom right)?

Comment: de.off() closes the window where the new plot opens, however, if i try another plot it will still open in a new tab, and the pane layout is just as before when i didn't have this problem, the plots pane is there but the generated plots won't show there